# How to make parent div show child div horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a following page structure:

```
----------------------------------------
|              |s|                 |
| top-content  |p|     details     |
|--------------|l|                 |
|s | tree      |i|                 |
|c |           |t|                 |
|r |           |t|                 |
|o |           |e|                 |
|l |           |r|                 |
|l |           | |                 |
|--|-----------| |                 |
|  |  scroll   | |                 |
-----------------------------------
```

The top content must be 'fixed' and always be shown above the tree in the left pane so I use the wrapper.

I have:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  direction: ltr;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tree-parent-div {
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
}

.tree-child-div {
  height: inherit;
  direction: ltr !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='top-content'>Here lies top content</div>
  <div class='tree-parent-div'>
    <div class='=tree-child-div'>Here lies the js tree</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use 'tree-parent-div' and 'tree-child-div' system instead of using only 'tree-child-div' because I need vertical scrollbar to be on the left side.

Here is the dilemma. I want both scrollbars to be in 'tree-parent-div'. Vertical scrollbar works well.
But when the content of 'tree-child-div' is bigger than the width of 'tree-parent-div' (for example there is a big number 4152674168794361742343847652361790349568463521678329456584736325145676 in the tree node name), the horizontal scrollbar is not visible.

Comment: can you show code that demonstrates the issue - the code you've shown has no scrolling required ... also `class='=tree-child-div'` typo

Comment: here is the example of code: https://jsfiddle.net/39276pv5/

I want the big number of the child div to cause the horizontal scrollbar in the parent div

Answer (score 0):

The `tree-child-div` needs to be `display: inline-block;` (or similar).
If you want your parent div to not be scrolled to the right initially, change the `direction` property.

```
.tree-child-div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing arises from the combination of the `direction: rtl` property and the `height: inherit` property within flex containers. This combination can create unexpected behaviors with scrollbars.

To achieve your goal (having both scrollbars inside `tree-parent-div`), you can utilize the `overflow` properties.

Here's a revised solution:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tree-parent-div {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Vertical Scroll */
  overflow-x: auto;   /* Horizontal Scroll */
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px); /* Adjust this value according to the height of your top-content */
  direction: rtl;
}

.tree-child-div {
  direction: ltr;
  width: max-content; /* This ensures that the width of this div is as wide as its content */
}

.top-content {
  height: 40px; /* example height, adjust accordingly */
}
```

Here's your HTML structure:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-content">Here lies top content</div>
  <div class="tree-parent-div">
    <div class="tree-child-div">Here lies the js tree with a big number 4152674168794361742343847652361790349568463521678329456584736325145676</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The key change here is adding `width: max-content;` to `.tree-child-div`. This ensures that the width of the child div is determined by its content. The `overflow-x: auto;` on `.tree-parent-div` ensures that if the child div overflows the parent in terms of width, the horizontal scrollbar appears on the parent.

Note: Ensure you have a fixed height (or max-height) for your `.wrapper`, or ensure it's contained within an element that has a fixed height, to make sure the vertical scrollbar works as expected.